# Display SubTotal and Total at the same time - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javasript and found the javascript code I used below from another source which I modified. I'm trying to display the subtotal on the third column for each benefit while displaying the total of the entire form. I'm having difficulty in displaying the Subtotal. Here's my code. Any help from you will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" style="font-size:10px;color: #1666AF; line-height:2.1;" width="280">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="60%"><span style="color: #DF2727; font-weight:bold;">Benefits</span></td>
            <td width="20%" align="center" ><span style="color: #DF2727; font-weight:bold;">Qty</span></td>
            <td width="20%"><span style="color: #DF2727; font-weight:bold;">Savings</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 1</td>
            <td align="center">
            <select id="qty" name="BENE_1_800" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >  
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> 
            </td>
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal_1">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 2</td>
            <td align="center"><select id="qty" name="BENE_2_266" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >  
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> 
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal_2">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 3</td>
            <td align="center"><select id="qty" name="BENE_3_100" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >  
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> </td>
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 4</td>
            <td align="center"><select id="qty" name="BENE_4_25" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >  
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> </td>
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 5</td>
            <td align="center"><select id="qty" name="BENE_5_25" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> </td>
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 6</td>
            <td align="center"><select id="qty" name="BENE_6_25" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >  
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> </td>
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Benefit 7</td>
            <td align="center"><select id="qty" name="BENE_7_773" onchange="CalculateEstimatedSavings(this.form)" >  
                    <option value="0">0</option>  
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select> </td>
            <td align="left"><span id="order_subtotal">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
&nbsp;

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" style="color: #1666AF; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;" width="280">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="62%"><span>Estimated Total Savings:</span></td>
            <td align="left" width="38%"><span id="total_savings">$0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
&nbsp;

<div style="width:280px; clear:both;"><a href="#" style="border:none; float:right;"><img src="start-saving_sm.png" /></a></div>
</fieldset>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function CalculateEstimatedSavings(frm) {
    var total_savings = 0

    // Run through all the form fields
    for (var i=0; i < frm.elements.length; ++i) {

        // Get the current field
        form_field = frm.elements[i]

        // Get the field's name
        form_name = form_field.name

        // Is it a "product" field?
        if (form_name.substring(0,4) == "BENE") {

            // If so, extract the price from the name
            item_price = parseFloat(form_name.substring(form_name.lastIndexOf("_") + 1))

            // Get the quantity
            item_quantity = parseInt(form_field.value)

            // Update the order total
            if (item_quantity >= 0) {
                total_savings += item_quantity * item_price
            }
        }
    }

    // Display the total rounded to two decimal places
    document.getElementById("total_savings").firstChild.data = "$" + round_decimals(total_savings, 2)

}

function round_decimals(original_number, decimals) {
    var result1 = original_number * Math.pow(10, decimals)
    var result2 = Math.round(result1)
    var result3 = result2 / Math.pow(10, decimals)
    return pad_with_zeros(result3, decimals)
}

function pad_with_zeros(rounded_value, decimal_places) {

    // Convert the number to a string
    var value_string = rounded_value.toString()

    // Locate the decimal point
    var decimal_location = value_string.indexOf(".")

    // Is there a decimal point?
    if (decimal_location == -1) {

        // If no, then all decimal places will be padded with 0s
        decimal_part_length = 0

        // If decimal_places is greater than zero, tack on a decimal point
        value_string += decimal_places > 0 ? "." : ""
    }
    else {

        // If yes, then only the extra decimal places will be padded with 0s
        decimal_part_length = value_string.length - decimal_location - 1
    }

    // Calculate the number of decimal places that need to be padded with 0s
    var pad_total = decimal_places - decimal_part_length

    if (pad_total > 0) {

        // Pad the string with 0s
        for (var counter = 1; counter <= pad_total; counter++) 
            value_string += "0"
        }
    return value_string
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are passing null into function, this.form doesn't exist. actually you didn't post part of html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this piece of code in your cycle, or move out of cycle to update only current tr's cell. In the `CalculateEstimatedSavings` function

```
 form_field.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent="$" + round_decimals( item_quantity * item_price, 2)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Srq9v/1/ look here

beware of `nextElementSibling` function, I'm not sure from when IE supports it.

Comment: Thank you Gena London for your response. but I checked it in Fiddle and it doesn't seem to update the third column? I'm using Firefox when I checked it.

Comment: try this one http://jsfiddle.net/Srq9v/1/
i've changed innerText property to textContent, which is supported by most browsers

Comment: Hi Gena! That's awesome. Thank you for not giving  up on me! You really saved my day...

Comment: No problem =) next time add more sexy humour (read your profile)